# Update Android app using Google Play Custom App Publishing API

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-developer-api, android-enterprise

I'm a developer working on a private app for my customer. The app has already been uploaded to the Google Play Store as a private app using the Google Play Console (Managed Google Play was used).

I found that it is possible to publish private apps through the Google Play Custom App Publishing API (https://developers.google.com/android/work/play/custom-app-api/publish) which significantly reduces the publishing time.

Is it possible to use the Google Play Custom App Publishing API to update the app if the app was publish with the Google Play Console?

If yes, is there any good example how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, it's not possible.

If the app was published using the Google Play Console (even if it was Managed Google Play) the Google Play Custom App Publishing API can't be used.

I had to unpublish my app in the Google Play Console and upload it using the Google Play Custom App Publishing API with a different app ID.